# How to get all elements of 2D array by slice in python

Tags: python, arrays, slice

I want to set value of `G[1][0],G[1][1]...G[1][100]` and `G[0][1],G[1][1]...G[100][1]` to be 1

```
G = [[0]*101]*101
G[1][:] = 1
G[:][1] = 1
```

Than I got error,

```
...
G[1][:] = 1
TypeError: can only assign an iterable
```

how can I do this without Numpy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few flaws here.

### First: Iterator assignment

First of all, the left-hand side of your assignment yields an iterable, so you can't assign a scalar to that. Instead, the right-hand side (in your case `1`) needs to be an iterable of equal length, e.g.:

```
G[0][:] = [0] * 101 # Warning: Copied code from question, still flawed
```

### Second: List of list references

You initialize your list in-line. This is okay for a list of literals, but will fail for the second dimension, as it will hold 101 references to the **same** internal list. Changing one element in there will have effects on all other indices.

You want to initialize your list like this:

```
G = [[0] * 101 for x in range(102)]
```

### Third: List slice / hard-copy

The next thing is, that the `[:]`-call creates a hard-copy of your list. So what happens here, is:

- `G[0][:]` takes the first column of your 2d list and hard-copies it.
- `G[:][0]` hard-copies the entire 2d list and then returns the first column of that.

You probably **do not** want to copy the entire list around all the time, losing its reference and making changes only to the copies.

### Finally: What you want

Assuming your first dimension refers to **columns** and your second dimension refers to **rows**:

Set all elements of a **column** to `1`:

```
G[0] = [1] * 101
```

Set all elements of a **row** to `1`:

```
for i in range(102): G[i][0] = 1
```

Comment: Amazing answer! What confused me most is the reason you explained in the second part. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

First of all the way you created the `list` is wrong

See this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

**Using loop:**

```
import pprint
lst = [[0]*10 for n in range(10)]
for i in range(len(lst[0][:])): #Iterating over column of first row
    lst[0][i] = 1
for j in range(len(lst)): #Iterating over row of first column 
    lst[j][0] =1
pprint.pprint(lst)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The TypeError you get is because you are trying to assign an int to a list.

The simplest solution I can think is a for loop over the length of the vector you want to set to 1:

```
for i in range(len(G[1][:])):
    G[1][i] = 1
```

edit:
I tested this code. It won't work for your set up as you instantiated G as a deep copy list of lists.

The proper way to instantiate your matrix would be:

```
 G = [[0 for x in range(101)] for x in range(101)]
```

Comment: So we cannot use slice to give a list a value. Got it, thank u!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to understand what `[[0]*101]*101` really does.
The type of `G` is `list of list`, but each entry in the outer list `G` is a reference to the same list. See [Python list of lists, changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly). Most of the time this is not what you want.

Second, `G[1][:]` is a slice and requires an iterable object on the right hand side. There are multiple ways to achieve setting all values in a row, because you can also set the entry to a new list. Since you need to change the values also in different rows, I recommend using for loops to begin with.

Comment: Greet! I think I understand why `G[1][:]` and `G[:][1]` do not include elements `G[2][2]` or `G[3][4]` but I got an all `1` array. Is it because "each entry in the outer list G is a reference to the same list." as you said?